# While Statement not work - just writing output of {}

Tags: powershell

So im currently working on a script that will give me a users Uptime of there device via powershell. now when I run this code it will take 1-2 seconds if the user is connected to the network but if there not then it will take 10+ seconds to just give me the error.

Here is the code:

```
$timeout = 3 ##seconds

Function Get-Uptime {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [String]$ComputerName
    )
    
    
    do {
        try {
            foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
                $pc = $ComputerName
                $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} -Name GetOS
                $diff = $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LocalDateTime) - $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
 
                $jobs = Get-Job
                $Condition = {param($jobs) 'Running' -notin $jobs.State }
                $ConditionArgs = $jobs
                $RetryInterval = 5 ## seconds
                ## Start the timer
                $timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        
                $properties = @{
                    'ComputerName' = $pc;
                    'UptimeDays' = $diff.Days;
                    'UptimeHours' = $diff.Hours;
                    'UptimeMinutes' = $diff.Minutes;
                    'UptimeSeconds' = $diff.Seconds;
                }
                $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
                #$jobs
                write-host `n 
                write-output $obj
        
            }
            
        }catch{
            Write-host -fore Red "An error has occurred - Cant connect to laptop"
        }
        
    }While(($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (& $Condition $ConditionArgs)){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryInterval
        $totalSecs = [math]::Round($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds,0)
        Write-Verbose -Message "Still waiting for action to complete after [$totalSecs] seconds..."
    }

    $timer.Stop()
}


$computercheck = read-host "Laptop Number: "


Get-Uptime $computercheck


write-host -fore Cyan "Press any key to exit"; read-host
```

Now the part im having an issue with is

```
While(($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (& $Condition $ConditionArgs)){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryInterval
        $totalSecs = [math]::Round($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds,0)
        Write-Verbose -Message "Still waiting for action to complete after [$totalSecs] seconds..."
    }
```

here is the output when i run the script
[image: Image of output]

Any advice on what might be wrong here would be much appreciated, orignally i thought maybe the try{}catch{} was causing an issue but doesnt seem like it.

Comment: so you have a `do { ... } while (...) { ... }`. Which is clearly a mistake. You probably wanted `do { ... } while (... & $scriptblock { ... })`. I guess this happens when you try to overcomplicate your code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Sorry im a little confused with what you mean, so your saying the code should be ` While (($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (& $Condition $ConditionArgs)) & $scriptblock{ ... }) `